# Windows form design with ListBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and trying to learn how to create windows form application.
I would like to design a screen as follows:

```
it should have 2 list :
List1             List2
NUM1              B
NUM2              A
ALP1              1
ALP2              2
```

This list should be a ListBox because the length may vary. And at the same time to match List1 with List2, I should be able to do it with a click of mouse.

For example - for matching If I click on NUM1 and then on 2 (of lIst2) it should be able to do that.

I am not sure how to do this.

I am able to create two Lists with help of Form(design) in visual studio 2008. But not sure how to add the second part where if a user selects something on list1 and select something on list2 by clicking on it.

Comment: I am reading head first c# but I am kinda stuck with this one.

Comment: Is this not a grid with two columns?  Given that you want selection to be synchronised between the two lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be a good place to get you started. there is some examples at the end. I'm thinking it sounds like you want to probably handle the selecetion changed events. from there you should be able to set the selected items you need/want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx